# Functions returning random values in C++. Can't find issue

Tags: c++

I am working on a program to accept user input for an age variable, then calculate the grade the person should be in. My code seems to be functioning as it should and is returning correct values. However; I am also getting two random integers along with these values. I have looked through this several times and can't find the issue. My code is as follows and is arranged in the manner it is to meet the standards for an acceptable program set by my professor as this is an assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gradecalculate (int age)

{

    int grade;

    if (age >= 6 && age <= 17)
    grade= age-5;
    return grade;
    // Program does nothing if # not in range.

}

bool messagereturn (int age)

{

    if (age < 5)
    {cout << "You are too young for school." << endl;}

    else if (age > 17)
    {cout << "You are too old for school." << endl;}

    else
    {cout << "You should be in grade " << gradecalculate (age) << "." << endl;}

}

bool greet (int age)

{

    if (age == 17)
    {cout << "Hello Senior!" << endl;}

}

int main ()

{

    int age;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;

    cout << messagereturn (age) << endl;
    cout << greet (age) << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

When I run this code (using codeblocks) the output is as follows and I am not receiving any error codes:

When entering 17-

```
Enter your age: 17
You should be in grade 12.
96
Hello Senior!
96
```

When entering 11 -

```
Enter your age: 11
You should be in grade 6.
96
11
```

Comment: `messagereturn` and `greet` are defined as returning values, but have no `return` statements. That constitutes undefined behavior.

Comment: Both `messagereturn()` and `greet()` are declared as return a `bool` value, but neither one of them actually returns anything. Also, since `gradecalculate()` is only called for ages 5-17, there is no need for it to check the age again. It is not good to write a function that has no return value under certain conditions.

Comment: I've used the random function, and it gave me random results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `messagereturn()` and `greet()` functions are declared as returning `bool` values, but neither one of them actually returns anything, so the values are random.  Since you are sending the return values to `std::cout`, but the functions send their own messages to `std::cout` directly, they should not be returning any `bool` values at all.

Also, since `gradecalculate()` is only called for ages 5-17, there is no need for it to check the `age` again. It is not good to write a function that has no `return` value under certain conditions.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int gradecalculate (int age)
{
    return age-5;
}

void messagereturn (int age)
{
    if (age < 5)
    {cout << "You are too young for school." << endl;}

    else if (age > 17)
    {cout << "You are too old for school." << endl;}

    else
    {cout << "You should be in grade " << gradecalculate (age) << endl;}
}

void greet (int age)
{
    if (age == 17)
    {cout << "Hello Senior!" << endl;}
}

int main ()
{
    int age;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;

    messagereturn (age);
    greet (age);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could merge the functions together and have it return a `std::string` that you then send to `std::cout`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int gradecalculate (int age)
{
    return age-5;
}

string messagereturn (int age)
{
    if (age < 5)
    {return "You are too young for school.";}

    else if (age > 17)
    {return "You are too old for school.";}

    else
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "You should be in grade " << gradecalculate(age);
        if (age == 17)
        {oss << "\n" << "Hello Senior!";}
        return oss.str();
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int age;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;

    cout << messagereturn (age) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your two functions `bool messagereturn (int age)` and `bool greet (int age)` expect a `bool` to be returned but you don't `return` anything, which could be the reason why you output two random integers.

I don't know what you expect to be returned from these functions, but here's your code returning `false` instead of nothing:

```
bool messagereturn (int age)

{

    if (age < 5)
    {cout << "You are too young for school." << endl;}

    else if (age > 17)
    {cout << "You are too old for school." << endl;}

    else
    {cout << "You should be in grade " << gradecalculate (age) << "." << endl;}
    return false;
}

bool greet (int age)

{

    if (age == 17)
    {cout << "Hello Senior!" << endl;}
    return false;
}
```

Also, in the function `int gradecalculate (int age)`, the `grade` variable is not initialized depending on the value of `age`. Here's your code with `grade` initialized to 0.

```
int gradecalculate (int age)

{

    int grade = 0;

    if (age >= 6 && age <= 17)
    grade= age-5;
    return grade;
    // Program does nothing if # not in range.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `greet()` and `messagereturn()` are declared as returning `bool` but they return nothing, change their declaration to `void greet(int age);` and `void messagereturn(int age)` also all the printing to cout is done within those functions, there's no need to do:

```
cout << messagereturn(age) << endl;
cout << greet(age) << endl;
```

remove the cout and endl parts, just leave the calls of the functions.

Finally

```
int gradecalculate (int age)
{

    int grade = 0; //initialize grade to something, else you're returning garbage when age < 6 or > 17

    if (age >= 6 && age <= 17)
    grade= age-5;
    return grade;
    // Program does nothing if # not in range.

}
```